# Pywin32 on Google App Engine?

Tags: excel, google-app-engine, com, spreadsheet, pywin32

I am considering ways to read/modify large Excel spreadsheets with formula support in python, on Google App Engine. I am fairly unfamiliar with how COM works but I was wondering if anyone has successfully implemented pywin32 on GAE - or whether there are inherently problems with doing so, or if it's just a bad idea in general.

It seems like the only possible solution for Python (xlrd has no formula support) but if it doesn't work, I will resort to learning Java and trying JExcel API.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's servers are not running Windows, so no, there's no way whatsoever to use any Win32 APIs.

Comment: Thanks; I think I will stick with JExcel API then :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use GAE then you may process some stuff on a windows machine. You can use Pull Queues to lease tasks from GAE process them and then add them to Push Queues that will store the data in GAE

Comment: There's no need (or way, practically speaking) to add the results to a push queue. Instead, just submit the results to the app as an HTTP request.

Comment: Remote API ;-) I have done it already on an Erlang system that was controlling python scripts that used Remote API. But a simple HTTP request is enough, on the other push task queues have rates than can be useful

Comment: There's no reason to use remote_api to create a task, though - remote_api itself requires an HTTP request, and you could just do the work in that request instead.

Comment: SO basically it's an overhead and adds some complexity overall but remote api has a cleaner API instead of creating a post request and conceptually it 's nice :)